# Storing Recurring Payment information in Database using Paypal pro

Tags: php, api, paypal, payment, recurring

I want to make an online enrollment system using Paypal pro API. I want to have an option to pay tuition fee  in an installment using Credit card. To do this , I am creating Recurring Payment profile using Paypal Pro. I am able to successfully create the recurring payment profile & store initial payment information into database.

Now When the next recurring payment happens, I want to store the the payment information into my database with some identity parameters such as Payee Id , PayeeEmail , PayeeEnrolledDepartmentId.

I have heard about IPN(Instant payment notification) Service in Paypal pro. But the main problem is , When i Create Recurring profile for the first time, I would like to send some Identity parameter such as Id, Email etc so that when the next time the IPN script is executed , I am able to recognize & store payment information with the correct identification.

How can I do this ? Please assist me with some useful techniques or codes.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: My Question is very simple ! I want Recurring Payment to be stored in Database with some identity string such as ID Which I wanted to send When My first Paypal Pro Recurring Payment is Created.  Than at next time when the Recurring payment happens, I want to pass back that Id along with the response. I Do not have any idea regarding this , How to do that..
//create  recurring payments profile using the details set above
$profile_recur = $paypal->createRecurringPaymentsProfile();

this is what i am using to Create Recurring profile using Recurring API which is successfully being created.

Answer (score 0):

When PayPal creates the profile, it will create and associate a profile ID with the buyer.  You could use this as a unique identifying value.  If you are wanting to pass over your own, you could pass over something in the description "DESC" variable.

Comment: Thank you I understood this, Now i am  able to get the profile id where I Created it. Now i will store this some where in DB & use for comparision  but how can i get that profile id in IPN(Instant payment Notification) page.